# For Kotlin Extended Button, how to include style?

Tags: kotlin, user-interface, button

I have extended the Button class within Kotlin:

```
class TabButton @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : Button(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    override fun onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(info: AccessibilityNodeInfo?) {
        super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(info)

        info?.text?.let {
            info.text = getContentDescription(it.toString())
        }
    }

    private fun getContentDescription(input: String): String {
        return this.resources.getString(R.string.tab_button_content_desc, input)
    }
}
```

in order to get the appropriate Content Description.  However, this TabButton is ignoring/not receiving the **style** associated with the button:

```
<com.foo.widgets.TabButton
    android:id="@+id/selection_scheduled"
    style="@style/Widget.Button.Filter"
```

What in my TabButton extension am I missing so that recognizes and applies the style?

Answer (score 1):

I’m AFK, so sorry if this wrong. I can’t test it.

You should subclass either AppCompatButton or MaterialButton (if you’re using a Material Components theme). The layout  inflater knows how to replace `Button` elements with one of these based on the theme, but it’s impossible to replace your button in a way that works since you’re not subclassing one of these.

Also, instead of using 0 as the default for the `defStyleAttr`, you should use whatever the superclass passes for that value. Look at the two-argument constructor of whichever of the two button classes you choose to subclass.

Comment: I started with AppCompatButton but neither AppCompatButton nor Button seems to respect style if I attempt to extend them.  I also tried with the two-argument constructor and neither seem to work with style.

Comment: Don’t use the two-argument super constructor. Use the three-argument super constructor like in your code above, but instead of passing 0 as the default value of the third parameter, pass whatever the superclass’s two-argument constructor passes to its three-argument constructor.

Comment: And if you are using a Material Components theme, you need to subclass MaterialButton, not AppCompatButton.